# How to download restricted backup config file on HG8245H router

Tags: router

I have HG8245H router and I want to download backup config file to which I dont have access as regular user in my case its caled `root`. So I downloaded firmware of my router and extracted it using binwalk and found .asp files in particlar [cfgfile.asp](https://pastebin.com/uhc33fKy) and [cfgfileroot.asp](https://pastebin.com/Rse2ayRr). Cfgfile.asp contain this snippet of java code below which is missing in page from where I should download configs so I opened `Inspect Elements in Firefox and add it in side java tags

```
function backupSetting() {
 
    var Form = new webSubmitForm();
    Form.setAction('cfgfiledown.cgi?&RequestFile=html/management/cfgfile.asp');
    Form.addParameter('x.X_HW_Token', getValue('onttoken'));
    Form.submit();
}
```

Also `cfgfileroot.asp` had missing html code so I added that to after regular code

```
  <table width="100%" height="5" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr> 
      <td> </td> 
    </tr> 
  </table> 
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr> 
      <td> <input style="width:150px" class="submit" name="saveconfigbutton" id="saveconfigbutton" type='button' onClick='SaveSetting()' BindText="s0709"> </td> 
      <td> <input style="width:150px" class="submit" name="btnsaveandreboot" id="btnsaveandreboot" type='button' onClick='SaveandReboot()' BindText="s070a"> </td> 
    </tr> 
  </table> 
</div> 
<table width="100%" height="18" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
  <tr> 
    <td> </td> 
  </tr> 
</table> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    if(curUserType != sysUserType)
    {
        document.write('<div id="downloadConfig" style="display:none"> ');
    }
    else
    {
        document.write('<div id="downloadConfig"> ');
    }
</script>

  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
    <tr> 
      <td class="prompt"> 
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
          <tr> 
            <td class="title_common" BindText="s070b"></td> 
          </tr> 
        </table>
      </td> 
    </tr> 
  </table> 
  <table width="100%" height="5" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr> 
      <td> </td> 
    </tr> 
  </table> 
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr> 
      <td> 
        <input class="submit" style="width:220px" name="downloadconfigbutton" id="downloadconfigbutton" type='button' onClick='backupSetting()' BindText="s070c" >
      </td> 
    </tr> 
  </table> 
</div> 
<form action="cfgfileupload.cgi?RequestFile=html/management/reset.asp&FileType=config&RequestToken=<%HW_WEB_GetToken();%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="fr_uploadSetting" id="fr_uploadSetting"> 
  
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    if(curUserType != sysUserType)
    {
        document.write('<div id="uploadConfig" style="display:none">');
    }
    else
    {
        document.write('<div id="uploadConfig">');
    }
</script>

    <table width="100%" height="10%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
      <tr> 
        <td class="prompt"> 
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
            <tr> 
              <td class="title_common" BindText="s070d"></td> 
            </tr> 
          </table>
        </td> 
      </tr> 
    </table> 
    <table width="100%" height="5" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
      <tr> 
        <td> </td> 
      </tr> 
    </table> 
    <table> 
      <tr> 
        <td BindText="s070e"></td> 
        <td> 
            <div class="filewrap"> 
            <div class="fileupload"> 
              <input type="hidden" name="onttoken" id="hwonttoken" value="<%HW_WEB_GetToken();%>"> 
              <input type="text" id="f_file" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" /> 
              <input type="file" name="browse" id="t_file" size="1"  onblur="StartFileOpt();" onchange="fchange();" /> 
              <input id="btnBrowse" type="button" class="submit" BindText="s070f" /> 
            </div> 
            </div>
        </td> 
        <td> <input class="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" type='button' onclick='uploadSetting();' BindText="s0710" /> </td> 
      </tr> 
    </table> 
  </div> 
</form> 

<script>
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
{
    var b = all[i];
    var c = b.getAttribute("BindText");
    if(c == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    b.innerHTML = ssmpLanguage[c];
}

var all = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
{
    var b = all[i];
    var c = b.getAttribute("BindText");
    if(c == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    b.value = ssmpLanguage[c];
}
</script>
```

Here is how it look's modified

[image]

After that I gone from this page displayed below

[image]

to

[image]

But when I click `Downlod configuration file` nothing happens :(

If you have HG8245 or HG8245H plese log in as in my case telecomadmin or user with wich you can access to backup config and send me content of https://192.168.100.1:80/html/managment/cfgfileroot.asp that page

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem with this router: I would need to get a configuration file. Did you solve it somehow? I bought new unlocked HG8245H router for experiments. I can send you content of cfgfileroot.asp. Please contact me.

Comment: Hi @Mato I was able to get `cfgfileroot.asp` but could not dump config file it does not want to dump it even when I click on backup button

Comment: Hi @Vido thanks for reply. It is a big pity. Have you any other idea? I see your other question https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26837/recreating-ping-command-injection-using-curl-instead-using-web-page-on-huawei-ro is the right way? Can I help you with something with full access to unlocked HG8245H? Thanks.

Comment: @Mato sorry I dont have any idea

Comment: :-( I found this https://github.com/logon84/Hacking_Huawei_HG8012H_ONT yet. It seems interesting, what do you think?