# Recreating ping command injection using curl instead using web page on Huawei router

Tags: injection, command-line, router

I have an ARM based Huawei router and Im trying to do injection vulnerability on page under diagnostics where's "ping" feature is. So first I tried this command `-c 1 127.0.0.1` and it worked

```
--- DNS Statistics ---
Server Response = Non-Existent Domain
WanIP = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Name = -c 1 127.0.0.1
Address = -
Aliases = -
Time = 15ms
--- Ping Statistics ---
Operation failed.
```

then I tried this command `127.0.0.1; echo -c 4` but I get

```
Test failed.
--- Ping Statistics ---
Operation failed.
```

and after some more google-ing I found this command `ping -c 5 "$(id)" and when I click on` start ping` it seams that's get stuck in some loop
I suspect that maybe shell is open, here is how it looks

[image]

So I want to recreate sending that command with curl, I created mine curl like this

[image]

I think `maintenancend.cgi` is resposable for ping requests. In [zip](https://mega.nz/file/IdBTDIiC#PB6zyLxzUNzEQzvTx6lUW01JEmJX315ZF4LvyEh9JQA) you will find `Diagnose Ping Configuration.html` and ARM `web` utility which is responsible for
.cgi web requests

Edit:
So I made request directly to my web ping page and it look's like this

[image]

first button should be `start` and second `stop` but they are in java so I need a way to refer to them by name. Also I found example of POST method on web end here it is

```
curl -X POST -F 'name=linuxize' -F 'email=linuxize@example.com' https://example.com/contact.php
```

but I need names of buttons/fields to supply and there is non in that "java button's". [Here](https://www.tazkranet.com/Esalny/HUAWEI-GPON/Route.htm) you can find emulated web UI

Comment: You may not be able to see the output; try a command that creates a connection or something. If you don't know how to use curl, you should read the manpage

Comment: man page for curl is huge but it seams that I need to read it all

Comment: Well the `-F` is usually for multi-part POST data, you should probably just use `--data` or its variants instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use the browser tools (F12 in most browsers) and check how request is sent when you perform the action in the web UserInterface. Some browsers even have a 'copy as cURL' context menu item for network requests.

Comment: I found how requests looks like `https://192.168.100.1:80/html/management/complex.cgi?x=InternetGatewayDevice.IPPingDiagnostics&RUNSTATE_FLAG=Ping&RequestFile=html/management/diagnose_common.asp` but I can't recreate java button pressed thing

Comment: you did no read my post I did used  browser tools to create my curl command